# Bounds on polynomial roots

Tags: polynomials, roots, upper-lower-bounds

I am looking to find the minimum absolute value of the roots of the following polynomial:
$$ux^M - x + 1$$
where $u$ and $M$ are constants. Does a closed form upper or lower bound expression exist?

M is a positive integer.

Comment: The roots would have a $\frac{-1}{Mu}$ in the terms adding up to the value of the roots if $M = 2$, else $0$.

Comment: I hope this is a useful observation for you to conclude from.

Comment: The sum of the roots for $M > 2$ is $0$, if you didn't understand my statement.

Comment: Somewhat connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/874997

Comment: Do you also need to know whether there are real roots at all?

Comment: @Spectre could you please elaborate on the $-\frac{1}{Mu}$ part?

Comment: The original problem I want to solve is to find the range of u as a function of M where all the roots of the equation are inside the unit circle.

Comment: Ahh, so is $x$ a complex value?  I had assumed real, previously.

Comment: Well, $\frac{-1}{Mu}$ is nothing but the average of roots. In the case of $M > 2$, this average is $0$.

Comment: Oh sorry, the numerator is not $-1$ , it is $1$.

Comment: There are many errors I made, I guess. I will post an answer for you to check with.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the substitution $x\mapsto1/z$ to get

$$z^M-z^{M-1}+u$$

and hence the roots $z$ are [bounded above](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots#Bounds_on_all_roots) by

$$1+\max(1,|u|)$$

and your roots are bounded below by

$$\frac1{1+\max(1,|u|)}$$